# PHP Optional Function Parameter Set to Reference to Existing Object

Tags: php, function, parameters

I don't even know if this is possible but I'm trying to set an optional value to an existing object.

Here is a simplified version of the code I'm trying.

```
<?php

class configObject {

private $dataContainer = array();

public function set($dataKey, $dataValue) {
  $this->dataContainer[$dataKey] = $dataValue;
  return TRUE;
}

public function get($dataKey) {
  return $this->dataContainer($dataKey);
}

$this->set('someValue', 'foobar');

} //End configObject Class

function getPaginationHTML($c = &$_config) {

  $someOption = $c->get('someValue');
  // Do other stuff
  return $html;
}

$_config = new configObject();

$html = getPaginationHTML();


?>
```

I'm getting the error:
 syntax error, unexpected '&' in

Any help is appreciated, again I'm not sure if it's even possible to do what I'm trying to do so sorry for being a noob.

Thanks

Comment: Since getPaginationHTML seems to be relative to your class why don't you define it as a method of the class? You can use the decorator pattern too.

Comment: Can you post an answer using the decorator pattern?   I don't want to add it to the configObject class because it only contains config info but if I can extend the class or something.  BTW I am using a dependency container for injection on config, database, session classes in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

example with the decorator pattern:

```
class ConfigObject {

    private $dataContainer = array();

    public function set($dataKey, $dataValue) {
        $this->dataContainer[$dataKey] = $dataValue;
        return true;
    }

    public function get($dataKey) {
        return $this->dataContainer[$dataKey];
    }

}

class ConfigObjectDecorator {
    private $_decorated;


    public function __construct($pDecorated) {
        $this->_decorated = $pDecorated;
    }

    public function getPaginationHTML($dataKey) {
        $someOption = $this->get($dataKey);
        // Do other stuff
        $html = '<p>' . $someOption . '</p>';
        return $html;
    }

    public function set($dataKey, $dataValue) {
        return $this->_decorated->set($dataKey, $dataValue);    
    }

    public function get($dataKey) {
        return $this->_decorated->get($dataKey);    
    }
}

class ConfigFactory {
    public static function create () {
        $config = new ConfigObject();
        return new ConfigObjectDecorator($config);
    }
}

$config = ConfigFactory::create();
if ($config->set('mykey', 'myvalue'))
    echo $config->getPaginationHTML('mykey');
```

Note that can easily rewrite `ConfigFactory::create()` to add a parameter to deals with other types of decoration (or none).